# Android SimpleListView1 C#

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin

I have implemented a SimpleListView1 layout in C# and am in need of adding a button to the list that allows for me to return home.  As there is no XML that I am capable of editing in this case I am looking for ideas on how to solve this minor predicament.

```
namespace SOA_App
{
[Activity(Label = "BasicTable")]
public class SOAList_ListView : ListActivity {
    string[] items;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
         base.OnCreate(bundle);
         items = new string[] { "Vegetables","Fruits","Flower Buds","Legumes","Bulbs","Tubers" };
         ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
    }

    protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        var t = items[position];
        Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, t, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular Activity (as opposed to a ListActivity), and then add a ListView and a Button widget to the Activity's layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "Home" to the list and onClick check if the text is "Home" but as Tom suggested why not create a normal activity with a button at the bottom?

I noticed you copy/pasted the Xamarin tutorial, I recommend creating a new project with editable (a)xml and add a listView and a button.